# windows app fonts to small

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, fonts

I have an application that was written in for Windows 98 and it looks the same running under Win XP. I have now tried to run it under Win 8.1 and the fonts for the entry fields are to small. It looks like 5 maybe 6 point. I messed with the display options and nothing seems to effect how this app displays. I am running it under compatibility Win XP SP3, but no luck. Is there a way to adjust the font size for an application from outside of the app?

Comment: You can run it in a VM for free: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7

Comment: @David XP Mode only exists in Windows 7, and this user is using Windows 8.1.

Comment: @techie007 I have the XP Mode's as an option to select it so I am guessing it is available.  It doesn't seem to make any difference what I choose there.

Comment: @StephanM Are you SURE you're using Windows 8 then? I ask because I promise, XP Mode is not part of Windows 8 (without hacking it in): "With the end of extended support for Windows XP in April 2014, Microsoft has decided not to develop Windows XP Mode for Windows 8." [Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2724115).  If you _upgraded_ from Windows 7 and had XP Mode installed you may have shortcuts left over that don't do anything, but the underlying system that provided XP Mode is gone.

Comment: @techie007 I had assumed that MS carried it over into 8, good to know.

Comment: @techie007 am running 8.1 and I have the ability for compatibility mode to run from Windows 95 to windows 8.  I was surprised to see it because I had heard the horror stories.  I installed with a new full lic. of win8.1

Comment: Putting a program in compatibility XP mode is not same thing as  the "XP Mode" David was referring to.  XP Mode is an XP VM that comes with Windows 7.  Check out David's link for more info.

Comment: Perhaps figure out what font on XP it's using and make sure your Windows 8,1 install has it as well.  It may be defaulting to a 'similar' font, and substituting the tiny font if it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you decrease the Screen Resolution, that should increase the appearance of fonts within apps that lack zoom features.

Comment: I dropped all the way to 640x480 all that really happen was I lost screen space.  The font remains tiny.

Comment: Assuming you've followed the basic instructions outlined here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/get-best-display-monitor, That's all I've got then. Which program are you trying to do this in? You may be able to increase the font size from within the program through other means.

Comment: its a custom app some company wrote that as far as I know no longer exist

Comment: yes I had tried all of that before looking for help on here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid, legal copy of XP, grab VirutalBox (free), or if your edition of Windows has it and your computer supports it, just turn on the Windows Hyper-V feature.

Either of these will provide you with a way to create and run VMs (Virtual Machines).

- Use whichever of those to create a VM.
- Install your legal XP onto it.
- Try your program from within that.

Comment: I am running my very much legal version of xp and my very much legal 8.1 within virtual Box 4.3.12.  I would like to try and run this under wine but that's not part of this discussion.

Comment: If you're running XP in VB as a VM on the Win8.1 machine, why wasn't this included in your original question?  Does it still have the font problem when doing that?  Not sure why you mention Wine, but yeah, it has nothing to do with this. :)

Comment: Yes I have always been running in VB and WINE is not really involved.  Even though that is where I would like to run it.